# How to fetch all Google Contacts in iOS 10

Tags: ios, ios10, google-contacts-api

I have tried to get all google contacts using Google Contacts APi but I didnt find anything working for iOS. OAuth is not working because google changed Policies for Using WebView OAuth. I get access-token using Google Sign In Framework but this token is invalid with google contacts API:
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full.

Please suggest for latest iOS SDK 10+ and latest google frameworks to fetch google/gmail Contacts

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [GIDSignIn Class](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in) for iOS to hanlde your OAuth problems.

please see ["Google Sign-In for iOS"](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/) Here is sample code to use GIDSignIn:

1. Get a reference to the GIDSignIn shared instance: GIDSignIn *signIn = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance];
2. Set the OAuth 2.0 scopes you want to request: [signIn setScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"]];
3. Call [signIn setDelegate:self];
4. Set up delegate method signIn:didSignInForUser:withError:.
5. Call handleURL on the shared instance from application:openUrl:... in your app delegate.
6. Call signIn on the shared instance;

You can also check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247694/get-google-contacts-using-api-on-ios) for additional info.

Answer (score 0):

> I ) Try  [GIDSignIn Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRI85.png) for Authentication :
>
> II ) import required classes as fallows :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>    
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<GIDSignInDelegate,GIDSignInUIDelegate,NSURLSessionDelegate>

@end
```

III) in viewDidLoad do as fallows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate = self;
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = "your_CLIENT_ID; //get from console
    [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] setScopes:@[@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts",@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"]];

    // Button for opening Google Auth //

    GIDSignInButton *button = [[GIDSignInButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f)];
    button.style = kGIDSignInButtonStyleWide;
    button.colorScheme  =kGIDSignInButtonColorSchemeLight;
    [button setCenter:self.view.center];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}
```

[image: sign in button]

IV ) as soon as the user finishes sign in handle it as below  by `GIDSignInUIDelegate`:

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error {

    // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
    NSString *userId = user.userID;                  // For client-side use only!
    NSString *idToken = user.authentication.idToken; // Safe to send to the server
    NSString *fullName = user.profile.name;
    NSString *givenName = user.profile.givenName;
    NSString *familyName = user.profile.familyName;
    NSString *email = user.profile.email;

    [self getPeopleList];
    // ...
}
// Implement these methods only if the GIDSignInUIDelegate is not a subclass of
// UIViewController.

// Stop the UIActivityIndicatorView animation that was started when the user
// pressed the Sign In button
- (void)signInWillDispatch:(GIDSignIn *)signIn error:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"0.0.");

}

// Present a view that prompts the user to sign in with Google
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

// Dismiss the "Sign in with Google" view
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn dismissViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

[image: user sign in process]

V ) now in `-(void)getPeopleList{}` you will find contacts :

```
-(void)getPeopleList{

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?personFields=emailAddresses"];

    NSURL *linkurl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];


    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:linkurl
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].currentUser.authentication.accessToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {
            NSDictionary *user_contact_json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
            NSLog(@"user_contacts %@", user_contact_json);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
        }
    }];

    [postDataTask resume];

}
```

[image: user contacts image]